# How to avoid re-render after i've added and Item to the list?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-functional-component

I have a functional component that needs to be updated.

```
export const VendorCategory = ({setShowProgress, user}) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const theme = useTheme()
    const listElements = []
    const [dummyCategory, setDummyCategory] = useState({
        "Test1": [
            "Subtest1", "Subtest2", "Subtest3"
        ],
        "Test2": [
            "Subtest1", "Subtest2", "Subtest3"
        ],
        "Test3": [
            "Subtest1", "Subtest2", "Subtest3"
        ]
    })


    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log("re-rendered")
        }
    })
    const AddSubCategory = useCallback(() => {
        setShowProgress(true)
        const newAdd = dummyCategory['Test1']
        newAdd.push("SubTest4")
        setDummyCategory({...dummyCategory, "Test1": newAdd})
        setShowProgress(false)
    },[setShowProgress,setDummyCategory,dummyCategory])



    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>

            <h3 className={classes.title}>Vendor Category</h3>

            <Button
                className={classes.button}
                variant='contained'
                color="primary"
            >
                Add Category
            </Button>
            <div className={classes.categoryDiv}>
                {
                    Object.keys(dummyCategory).map((value, index) => {
                        return (
                            <List>
                            <Accordion key={uuid()} mt={2}>
                                <AccordionSummary
                                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
                                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                                    id="panel1a-header"
                                >
                                    <ListSubheader key={uuid()} className={classes.sublistHeader} component="div"
                                                   id="nested-list-subheader">
                                        {value}
                                    </ListSubheader>
                                </AccordionSummary>


                                <AccordionDetails className={classes.subCategoryList}>
                                    <Button
                                        className={classes.button}
                                        variant='contained'
                                        color="primary"
                                        onClick={AddSubCategory}
                                    >
                                        Add Sub-Category
                                    </Button>
                                    {dummyCategory[value].map((subvalue, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <ListItem button key={subvalue}>
                                                <ListItemText inset primary={subvalue}/>
                                            </ListItem>
                                        )
                                    })}

                                </AccordionDetails>
                            </Accordion>
                            </List>)
                    })
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(VendorCategory)
```

the problem is the accordion is re-rendered every time I add an item to it and then it collapses.
how do I stop it from collapsing due to re-render?UseCallback hook also re-renders. how do i use React.Memo to avoid this?
Or how do I use useEffect in such a case. Again, I need to add an item without the accordion collapsing. is it possible?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you have an option you could set on the accordion to define its state (open/closed) ?

Comment: If your accordion is collapsing then the issue is not so much that it is being rerendered, but it is being remounted. The most likely cause is that you are not using stable keys - `key={uuid()}` will generate a new key on every render hence React thinks it's a new component. Keys should be unique and never change for the lifespan of a component.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion...ill give it a try and get back to you. :)

Comment: please make the above statement a reply so I can give you a like. u saved me a lot of research :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, mapped React elements should be given unique, stable keys that persist throughout the lifespan of the element. When a key changes, as far as React is concerned then a new component has been mounted.

Functions called inline on an element or component like `key={uuid()}` or `onClick={handleClick()}` will be called on *every render*. In this case, calling `uuid()` inline was generating a new key for every render of the parent component, causing the mapped child components to be remounted.

Answer (score 0):

React.memo avoids the re-render. In your Accordion function, try:

```
import {memo} from 'react';

const Accordion = (props) => {
    //your code
};

export default memo(Accordion);
```